# How to implement "Two finger swipe" gesture in android?

Tags: java, android, gesture

I have researched a lot but I couldn't find even a blog that tell about MultiTouch events. All are giving tutorials on single swipe. I wish to apply fling and 2 finger swipe both in same activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution myself after trying and failing a lot

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  

    Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent: " + event.getAction());
    //with the getPointerCount() i'm able to get the count of fingures
    if(event.getPointerCount()>1){
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                // This happens when you touch the screen with two fingers
                mode = SWIPE;
                // event.getY(1) is for the second finger
                p1StartY = event.getY(0);
                p2StartY = event.getY(1);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                // This happens when you release the second finger
                mode = NONE;
                float p1Diff = p1StartY - p1StopY;
                float p2Diff = p2StartY - p2StopY;

               //this is to make sure that fingers go in same direction and 
               // swipe have certain length to consider it a swipe
                if(Math.abs(p1Diff) > DOUBLE_SWIPE_THRESHOLD
                        && Math.abs(p2Diff) >DOUBLE_SWIPE_THRESHOLD &&
                        ( (p1Diff>0 && p2Diff>0) || (p1Diff < 0 && p2Diff<0) ))
                {
                    if(p1StartY > p1StopY)
                    {
                        // Swipe up
                        doubleSwipeUp();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Swipe down
                        doubleSwipeDown();
                    }
                }
                this.mode = NONE;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if(mode == SWIPE)
                {
                    p1StopY = event.getY(0);
                    p2StopY = event.getY(1);
                }
                break;
        }

    }
    else if(event.getPointerCount() == 1){
       //this is single swipe, I have implemented onFling() here
        this.gestureObject.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}
```